# Does not contain query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  I am trying to run a "does not contain" query.  My basic syntax is:

```
SELECT
*
FROM some_table
WHERE
some_column <> '%some_text%'
```

I would expect this to return all records that do not contain the text "some_text" anywhere in the some_column string.  However, the actual result set is returning records that *do* contain "some_text" somewhere in the string.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you need to leave out the % when not using "like"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try:

```
SELECT
*
FROM some_table
WHERE
some_column NOT LIKE '%some_text%'
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that.